# How I can send a parameter by reference in a block in obj-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, reference, block

Do you know how I can send a parameter by reference in a block?

My function is similar to this:

I tried with this code:

```
//The function 
-(void)downloadObjects:(NSMutableSet**)set handler:(void(^block)(void))handler{
...
code
...
}
```

and this call

```
-(void)myFunction{
   __block NSMutablesSet *objects = [NSMutableSet new];
   [self downloadObjects:&objects handler:^(void(^block)(void)){
      [self show:objects];
   }];
}
```

And I receive a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error because my "objects" variable was deallocated before the use

I know that I can receive the objects by block response, but in my real case I want to receive it in this mode.

Comment: What are you wanting to do that will require this?

Comment: In a block function I download and store the items but after for each object downloaded I want to download the correlated object, but my block is builded for a specific object for all request and I don't want change it for one method

Comment: I'm not sure I understand though. You said you don't want to receive it by response. I assume you mean as a parameter in the block? You can just receive it as an input parameter to the block and save it to a property or something. It is pretty much identical to what you are currently doing but less complicated.

Comment: I agree with you, maybe is complicated and maybe not really correct. But my block is a particular block similar to AFNetworking block with success and failure branch and other parameter and I don't want change it only for this function

Comment: Why do you pass pointer to pointer (`&objects`) yo your `-downloadObjects:handler:` method? Is it exactly what you want? BTW, `objects` should not deallocate until block is deallocated under ARC, so make sure your block is alive.

Comment: Pointers are always passed by reference. You don't need `**`, just `*` is enough. No `&` needed.

Comment: Thanks guys is solved sending parameter without a reference without a pointer. The problem was the pointer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to pass your NSMutableSet to a block like this, you are only going to have memory management issues for no reason. You only need it this way if you want to return some value like an NSError.